# Different branchs of $w^{1/3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity, branch-cuts

> Find a branch $g(w)$ of $w^{1/3}$ which serves as the inverse function $f(z)=z^3$ with $\text{dom}(f)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}^\times\mid \text{Arg}(z)\in[0,2\pi/3)\}$. Relate $g(w)$ to the principle branch $\sqrt[3]w$.

So I've identified that I should take the domain to be $\mathbb{C}^+=\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$, and then do something like
$$g(w)=\zeta \sqrt[3]{|w|}e^{i\text{Arg(w)/3}}=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{|w|}e^{i\text{Arg(w)/3}}.$$
But this is just a guess based on the same kind of thing for $w^{1/2}$ so it's is probably wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut the $w$-plane from $0$ to $\infty$ along the real axis.
Note that $w^{1/3}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$.  Choose the branch for which $0\le \arg(w)<2\pi$.

---

> Note that we could have chosen the $n$th branch such that $2n\pi \le \arg(w) <2(n+1)\pi$.

---

Let $w=z^3$.  Then $0\le \arg(z)<2\pi/3$.

Finally, $\arg(w)=\text{Arg}(w)$ in the upper-half plane and $\arg(w)=\text{Arg(w)}+2\pi$ in the lower-half plane.  So, we have

$$g(w)=\begin{cases} |w|^{1/3}e^{i\text{Arg}(w)/3}&,0\le\text{Arg}(w)<\pi\\\\|w|^{1/3}e^{i2\pi/3}e^{i\text{Arg}(w)/3}&,-\pi\le\text{Arg}(w)<0\end{cases}  $$

And we are done.

Comment: What branch is that exactly? Sorry

Comment: The branch cut is defined as the ray from $0$ to $\infty$ along the real axis.

Comment: Isn't the branch $g(w)$?

Comment: oh I was right thanks

Comment: wait was there any reason why you deleted it just then?

Comment: I corrected an erratum.

Comment: what happened to $w^{1/3}=|w|^{1/3}e^{i\pi/3}e^{iArg(w)/3}$

Comment: That was not correct.  In the upper-half plane there is no factor of $e^{i\pi/3}$ and in the lower-half plane the factor is $e^{i2\pi/3}=\frac{-1+i\sqrt 3}{2}$.

Comment: This kind of makes sense, but why you have $e^{i2\pi/3}$ in the lower-half plane?

Comment: In the upper-half plane $\text{Arg}(w)=\arg(w)$.  But in the lower_half plane, $\arg(w)=2\pi+\text{Arg}(w)$.  So, in the lower-half plane $\arg(w)/3=2\pi/3+\text{Arg}(w)/3$.  Can you finish now?